# Using "le" in expressions like "Si vous le voulez"

Tags: pronoms

> Si vous **le** voulez, nous pouvons aller au restaurant ce soir.
>
> Comme vous pouvez **le** voir, il ne fait pas bon aujourd'hui.

In these sentences, should *le* be used or not? Or is it optional? In English we normally wouldn't include it:

"If you want, we can ..." rather than "If you want **it**, we can ..."

"As you can see, ..." rather than "As you can see **it**, ..."

Comment: If you want to [go out tonight for dinner], we can go out for dinner. Bear in mind that in the second sentence, if you do not use LE, you would then actually be saying: /As you can see/ in the sense of not being blind. The verb constater here is better than voir...,.,.That is why the LE is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of the pronun "*le*" as direct object in these sentences is just a question of register.

You use it when you want a formal language.

The same sentences without this pronun are correct, there are informal and colloquial languages.

Answer (score 0):

This is not mandatory but improve the comprehension. "Le" is refering to the second part of sentence which is the purpose of the sentence.